# Call Parse.com REST services from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, servlets, parse-platform, httpurlconnection

I have created a database in the Parse.com cloud. I now need to write a Servlet in my Google App Engine application to call the REST services on Parse. The REST services require 
user authentication which is the Parse app id and the Javascript key.

```
...
            URL url = new URL("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/OBJECT");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            Base64 enc = new Base64();
            String userpassword = "{PARSE_APP_ID}" + ":" + "javascript-key={PARSE_JS_KEY}";
            String encodedAuthorization = enc.encodeBase64String(userpassword.getBytes());
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
...
```

I use org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 for encoding to get REST call authenticated.

The Parse.com REST API recommends using the following request format to make a HTTP call:

```
https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

The problem is that I kept getting

> {"error":"unauthorized"}

Is there anyone having the experience with working with calling a authenticated REST service?  Thanks!

EDIT.

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/OBJECT");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "{APP_ID}");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "REST_ID");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

I still got the same error while the responseCode was "200".

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the header version of authentication instead:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "app id here");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "rest key here");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am still getting the same error after I made the change.

Comment: are you sure you're using the right app id and rest key?  the unauthorized message is saying otherwise.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s53/sh/0b483880-ef94-4918-8e18-2056263b0bc1/7c4d070a001adb36cbb602f497989fc4

Comment: Yes, I am sure the APP ID and REST API KEY are both correct. I am behind a corporate proxy. But this shouldn't matter as I can get a response from Parse.com, should it?

Comment: Yeah, I can get the correct result from a CURL request from the network. It gave me a JSON result.

Comment: Are you able to log/debug/check the actual request made from GAE?

Comment: Sory Fosco. I am unable to get Request body.